# Disable highlighting matching parenthesis in insert mode in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to disable the highlight of matching parenthesis in Vim only in insert mode?

Using `:NoMatchParen` will disable it in both normal and insert mode.

**Edit:**
I tried using autocmd as suggested in a comment, and I have now in my .vimrc the lines

```
au InsertEnter * NoMatchParen
au InsertLeave * DoMatchParen
```

However, with this, when I have two buffers in a split, leaving the insert mode changes the buffer I'm in. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add autocmd's to execute when you enter or leave InsertMode have a look here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#InsertEnter